# Custom context menu not working on HTML Video tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering on how to create my own context menu on top of HTML video tag (something like the youtube menu).

[image]

I am using a library called [rClick.js](http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Browser-Context-Menu-Replacement-Plugin-With-jQuery-rClick-js.html)

Code snippet

```
<video id="video1" class="videoMenu" width="33.33%"  style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">
              <source src="./assets/samples/trailer.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
            </video>
<script src="assets/js/rclickcontextMenu/rclick.min.js"></script>
<script type="type/javascript">
$(function(){
  $(window).rClick({
    click: null, // right click
    element: $('#context-menu')
  });
});
```

```
<div id="context-menu" class="hidden">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Copy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Paste</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
</ul>
```

Somehow the library doesn't work like it should be, it shows the default menu instead. Is it a problem with HTML Video Tag (I couldn't find any existing example after some extensive research for a few days)?
[image]

Comment: Is your console giving you any errors?

Comment: Nope..... everything seems fine

Comment: Do you have a site for a live preview? Also, if your context menu is underneath the script, it's *possible* that it is trying to find a non-rendered element.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is currently (25/12/2016) only supported in Firefox.
Try this (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_oncontextmenu) in different browsers.

If you would like to provide a context menu for all browsers, you can disable the default menu in javascript and draw a new one yourself. There are some existing codes in GitHub for your purpose. I personly draw the menu myself. You can refer to http://www.voidtricks.com/custom-right-click-context-menu/ for more details.

Comment: it seems like a comment than an answer. please add some point to make it more clear.